# Passing node in context as a parameter while calling an XSLT Template

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<Data>
   <Entry>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <First_Name>A</First_Name>
      <Last_Name>B</Last_Name>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <First_Name>C</First_Name>
      <Last_Name>D</Last_Name>
   </Entry>

   <Entry>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <First_Name>E</First_Name>
      <Last_Name>F</Last_Name>
   </Entry>
</Data>
```

I have this example XML which loosely describes my real input XML. I am trying to pass the node `<Entry>` to a template inside an `<xsl:for-each>` loop.

Following portion of XSLT describes my current (faulty) XSL code:

```
<xsl:template match="Data">
   <xsl:for-each select="Entry">

   <!-- Some processing goes here which requires this loop -->

      <xsl:call-template name="makeRecord">     
         <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>

   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="makeRecord">
   <xsl:param name="node"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$node/First_Name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem that I am facing is that all the data is getting outputted, but I want only the value of the child node I specified i.e., `<First_Name>` to be in the output for each `<Entry>`. I suspect my use of the template parameter as `$node/First_Name` is at fault here. I have to have the for loop in my XSLT though. Can anyone please suggest how to correctly reference the child node values of the node passed as parameter to a template? I tried with the apply-template method as well, but same problem persists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. The output I get is `ACE` which is correct. I tested it with XSLT-1.0 and XSLT-2.0 as well.

Comment: The problem you report cannot be reproduced using your code: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDjS. -- Note that calling a named template does not change the context - so you could produce the same output without passing the node as the parameter: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDjS/1

Comment: Looks like the bug in my code was elsewhere than the area focused here. Got that resolved. The piece of "named template not changing context" helps.

Answer (score 0):

--ANSWERING MY OWN QUESTION---

Looks like the bug to my actual code was elsewhere than what is mentioned here. Keeping this question alive if anyone needs to know how to pass nodes to a template as parameter. Do make sure to check the comments of the question for a better solution!